# Clearing <select> when no options match the filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am actually working on a web interface and I am using a select. The select is there so the user can choose in a list of options and this will affect the entire page.

I added a filter to help the user finding the option he is looking for, and it works.

Here is my select and the filter call:

```js
function filtrer_saisie(quoi, id_list) {
  $("#" + id_list + " option").addClass('hidden');
  $("#" + id_list + " option").removeProp('selected');
  $("#" + id_list + ' option:containsIgnoreCase("' + quoi + '")').filter(':first').prop('selected', true);
  $("#" + id_list + ' option:containsIgnoreCase("' + quoi + '")').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="rechercher_station" placeholder="Rechercher une station" onkeyup='filtrer_saisie($(this).val(),"staSelect");' />
<select id="staSelect">
<option value="momuproE">MoMuPro</option>
<option value="560">Banteux RD917</option>
<option value="901">Bergues</option>
<option value="554">CD25_1</option>
<option value="555">CD25_2</option>
<option value="556">CD25_3</option>
<option value="557">CD25_4</option>
<option value="558">CD25_5</option>
<option value="559">CD25_6</option>
</select>
```

When the input value matches no option, it just leaves the last match in the select while disabling it. I want the select to show a blank space or maybe a few words like `No options found`.

Thanks!

Comment: To make your code snippet work, you may have to add jQuery to your html. Also where are your `option`s?

Comment: Done, sorry about that !

Comment: Do you not have any `option`s?

Comment: I add the `option`s with ajax. I'm getting data from json and add add it in the options. I added it in the code.

Comment: Thanks for adding! is `option:containsIgnoreCase` working for you? I'm only seeing errors like `unsupported pseudo: containsIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I mentioned in the comments, I don't think `option:containsIgnoreCase` is valid, so I made my own filter function that does pretty much the same thing:

```
$("#" + id_list + ' option').filter((i, optionElem) => {
  // lowercase text coming from each option
  let optionText = $(optionElem).text().toLowerCase();
  // keep option text if it includes lowercased searched value
  return optionText.includes(quoi.toLowerCase());
})
```

Explanation of the function is in comments in the code :) Let me know if you want me to explain anything.

I replaced that with your lines with `//$("#" + id_list + ' option:contains("' + quoi + '")')`, which gave rise to:

```
let found = $("#" + id_list + ' option').filter((i, optionElem) => {
  // lowercase text coming from each option
  let optionText = $(optionElem).text().toLowerCase();
  // keep option text if it includes lowercased searched value
  return optionText.includes(quoi.toLowerCase());
})
// next, get first (as you did), select it, and remove 'hidden' class
.filter(':first').prop('selected', true).removeClass('hidden');
```

As you can see, I stored this into a variable `found` so I can later check how many options were found, then decide what to do from there. Here's how those checks look:

```
// create new blank option -> add any text you want here :)
let blank = $('<option id="blank-option" value="">No matches</option>');

// if input value matched at least 1 option, remove the 'blank' element
if (found.length > 0) {
  $("#blank-option").remove();
}
// otherwise, if no matches were found, append the element & make it selected
else {
  $("#" + id_list).append(blank);
  blank.prop('selected', true);
}
```

Putting it all together in your original function:

```js
function filtrer_saisie(quoi, id_list) {
    $("#" + id_list + " option").addClass('hidden');
    $("#" + id_list + " option").removeProp('selected');
     
    let found = $("#" + id_list + ' option').filter((i, optionElem) => {
      // lowercase text coming from each option
      let optionText = $(optionElem).text().toLowerCase();
      // keep option text if it includes lowercased searched value
      return optionText.includes(quoi.toLowerCase());
    })
    // next, get first (as you did), select it, and remove 'hidden' class
    .filter(':first').prop('selected', true).removeClass('hidden');
    
    // create new blank option -> add any text you want here :)
    let blank = $('<option id="blank-option" value="">No matches</option>');
    
    // if input value matched at least 1 option, remove the 'blank' element
    if (found.length > 0) {
      $("#blank-option").remove();
    }
    // otherwise, if no matches were found, append the element & make it selected
    else {
      $("#" + id_list).append(blank);
      blank.prop('selected', true);
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="rechercher_station" placeholder="Rechercher une station" onkeyup='filtrer_saisie($(this).val(),"staSelect");' />
<select id="staSelect">
<option value="momuproE">MoMuPro</option>
<option value="560">Banteux RD917</option>
<option value="901">Bergues</option>
<option value="554">CD25_1</option>
<option value="555">CD25_2</option>
<option value="556">CD25_3</option>
<option value="557">CD25_4</option>
<option value="558">CD25_5</option>
<option value="559">CD25_6</option>
</select>
```

P.S. I used this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efa46cku/5/) to mess with things till it worked- feel free to mess with it if you want.